# How can I show that $\int _{E } t^{-1 } dt $, $E \in (0,1) $, is unbounded for some interval $E $, howewer small I make the interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can I show that $\int _{E } t^{-1 } dt $, $E \in (0,1) $, is unbounded for some **interval** $E $, howewer small I make the interval.

I first thought of taking the interval $[1/(1+n,1/n ]$, but this would give a limit that approaches $- \infty $ and $+ \infty $

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the unbounded behavior of $t^{-1}$ occurs at 0.   so you don't want to bound your interval away from 0.   Instead, start at 0 and go up to any epsilon,   $(0,\epsilon)$.

Now your integral is an improper integral, so it can be written as 
$\lim _{b\to 0}\int _b ^\epsilon  x^{-1} dx=\lim _{b \to 0} (\ln (\epsilon)-\ln (b))$
natural log of epsilon is a fixed number,  and the natural log of b goes to $-\infty$ as b goes to 0,  hence your limit is $\infty$